# grab html custom attr value with jquery

Tags: jquery

The HTML part:

```
<div title="Find on Amazon" data-value="54588047" class="btn btn-default btnAmazon" style="padding-top:5px !important" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#FindOnAmazonModal"><i class="fa fa-bullseye"></i></div>
```

Jquery part:

```
var id = $("data-value").val();
```

Please read above code carefully. My goal is to grab "data-value" attribute value and set it on "id" variable. the jquery part not working. any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it like this:

```
var id = $(".btnAmazon").attr("data-value");
```

`$(".btnAmazon")` will select the element, and `.attr("data-value")` will take the value of the attribute

**Demo**

```js
var id = $(".btnAmazon").attr("data-value");
console.log(id)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div title="Find on Amazon" data-value="54588047" class="btn btn-default btnAmazon" style="padding-top:5px !important" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#FindOnAmazonModal"><i class="fa fa-bullseye"></i></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Better to get data attribute like:

```
var id = $(".btnAmazon").data("value");
```